# Struggling with logic to split text into an array

Tags: java, regex, string, text, format

So after some process, I have a text like this:

```
18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 12h20 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) KL0646 Inflight services: Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details 17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 13h43 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details  12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 19h10 New York (JFK) 2 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Inflight services: FromUSD 864 View flight details
```

I would like to split the text in a way like this:

```
18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 12h20 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) KL0646 Inflight services: Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details 
17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 13h43 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details 
12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 19h10 New York (JFK) 2 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Inflight services: FromUSD 864 View flight details
```

Where each line is an array index.

I know using methods like `string.split();` can split the string by character but I cant figure out how that would work here. Using `string.split(" - ");` would not split it in the right place.

Say the string were like

`18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Some Text # 17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Some Text # 12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Some Text......`
Then using `string.split("#");` would do the trick for me.

So how can I get the format that I want with the given text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split using whitespace followed by a positive lookahead which asserts the beginning of the next duration substring:

```
String input = "18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 12h20 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) KL0646 Inflight services: Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details 17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 13h43 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details  12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 19h10 New York (JFK) 2 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Inflight services: FromUSD 864 View flight details";
String[] durations = input.split("\\s+(?=\\d{2}:\\d{2} - \\d{2}:\\d{2})");
for (String duration : durations) {
    System.out.println(duration);
}
```

This prints:

```
18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 12h20 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) KL0646 Inflight services: Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details
17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 13h43 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details
12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 19h10 New York (JFK) 2 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Inflight services: FromUSD 864 View flight details
```

This approach should be viable so long as a time range only appears at the very beginning of a substring (and all substrings would always begin with this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
String regex = "(?=(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d) - (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d))";

String[] split = text.split(regex);
Arrays.asList(split).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
18:50 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 12h20 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) KL0646 Inflight services: Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details 
17:27 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 13h43 New York (JFK) 1 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Lowest fare USD 862 View flight details  
12:00 - 13:10(+1 day) Trip duration 19h10 New York (JFK) 2 x transfer Includes travel by bus Maastricht (ZYT) Inflight services: FromUSD 864 View flight details
```